# var conforms a protocol which has associateType

Tags: swift, generics, protocols

I made a protocol which has `associatedType`.

```
public protocol HBPrerollProtocol: NSObjectProtocol {
    associatedtype HBContentType

    func set(content: HBContentType, startImmediately: Bool) // set configuration and begin
}
```

And I'm trying to create a view which has a property conforms above protocol.

```
open class HBPrerollPlayerView: HBPlayerView {
    open var preroll: HBPrerollProtocol?
}
```

However this doesn't work because the protocol has `associateType`. The error was as below:

> Protocol 'HBPrerollProtocol' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements

So I tried to make a view which conforms `HBPrerollProtocol` and make the var is this view.

```
class HBPrerollView<T>: UIView, HBPrerollProtocol {
    typealias HBContentType = T
    func set(content: HBContentType, startImmediately: Bool) { }
}
```

and

```
open class HBPrerollPlayerView<T>: HBPlayerView {
    open var preroll: HBPrerollView<T>?
}
```

This result a different error:

> Property cannot be declared open because its type uses an internal type

Because this classes are in a separated module I must make the type generic so I can use this classes with different modules.

My questing here is:

1. Is there a way to make a var conforms protocol which has `associatedType`?
2. If not, how can I make generic type `T` open or public?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
public protocol HBPrerollProtocol: NSObjectProtocol {
    associatedtype HBContentType

    func set(content: HBContentType, startImmediately: Bool) // set configuration and begin
}

open class HBPrerollPlayerView<T: HBPrerollProtocol>: HBPlayerView {
    open var preroll: T?
}
```